# After updating to 22.04 Eclipse PDT crashes during use

Tags: java, 22.04, crash, eclipse

As per the title, ever since updating from 20.04 to 22.04.1 Eclipse has started crashing randomly after a period of use.
This is happening on two different machines - a laptop and a desktop.
Sometimes it just freezes with a popup saying Java is unresponsive wait/quit, and sometimes it closes by itself.
Sometimes it then wont restart without rebooting the whole system

I have had several other problems since updating but none as disastrous as this (eg error messages flashing up too fast to read on boot, icons disappearing, drag-drop into any browser window not working)

Anyone else experiencing this? Is the update routine actually buggy - odd that it is happening on two different machines.

Comment: If you had it install before the update, try a reinstall. As far as i can see only the software in a fresh install are "guaranteed" to survive a release upgrade. All else is "might survive". Expect more complex packages / installs to have a higher failure rate. Because of this a fresh install is (and will probably remain) the absolutely best option. This is especially valid when there are larger changes - i.e. the move to wayland here.

Comment: try reinstalling dependencies.

Comment: What Eclipse version does this relate to? And what is it doing at the time of the crash? I had various issues with Netbeans after upgrading Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04. It might be a coincidence, but it might also be a commonality.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like the problem is me going for an unnecessary update - should have stuck with 20.04. If it aint broke, don't fix it - but now I have, and given all of the other problems and niggles, it looks like the only sensible course is a complete reinstall of everything. Blooming nuisance as it will mean recreating all of the settings and options for all of the extra software I have. Eclipse just crashed again mid-work, simply completely disappeared with no warning.

Comment: Eclipse v 2022-06

Comment: Its also affecting me, on other flavours of eclipse too. I'm looking for the root cause but still could find it...

Comment: Looks like a bug using wayland: https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/issues/158

Comment: There's a workaround solution: check https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/issues/158#issuecomment-1252708824

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a problem with Wayland.
Simple solution - turn of Wayland and switch back to X11.
Logout of Ubuntu. Start to log in again and click the icon that has appeared at bottom right of the screen - that gives you the option to disable Wayland.
The setting is remembered for the user.
A more complete fix is to remove Wayland altogether - it isn't needed.